# How can I host a site from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I recently downloaded this new app called Track My Coupon and the one cool feature that I like is the ability to access a site off of the iPhone. The way they have it is the user has their iPhone connected to a wifi network that their computer is on and browse to the iPhone ip. What I am trying to get to is how did they do this? Is their an API to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) is smart HTTP Server for iOS

Comment: I also discovered this if anyone else is interested.http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html

Comment: CocoaHTTPServer is more powerful and flexible, but in Matt Gallagher's article you have clearly explained how HTTP server works. In my opinion - you should read and analize this article, and use CocoaHTTPServer :)

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, I might try that. I am on a tight schedule so I might have to implement Matt's before I can try it with CocoaHTTPServer